# Gmail spam from contacts. How does it work?

Tags: email, gmail

I don't know why it seems IMPOSSIBLE to find a blog or any security expert explaining the procedure of how this 'hack' works.

My wife is receiving emails from people she's emailed through Gmail telling her that she they are getting spam from her email address (3 people, one forwarded the email with single link spam).  Some interesting features of these emails:

- the email contains her correct email (yes I know this can be spoofed)
- the email contains the contact's correct email

So in order for this 'hack' to happen, the spammer needs access to:

1. Her Gmail Contacts list
2. Her sent emails directly
3. Facebook friend emails
4. 1-3 for one of her Contacts
5. 1-3 for a mutual contact of both her and her contact and the spammer just tries mass guessing

My questions are:

1. What are the most likely steps for how this 'hack' occurs?
2. What are other possible ways this 'hack' occurs?
3. Are there *ANY* resources online which explain how this works: Wired articles, SE posts (I've searched, only a YAHOO CSRF), *ANYTHING* which gets in any more detail than future prevention?

I'd love to see ANYTHING with more technical detail than 'what you do next' posts.  (A Google search brings back nothing.)

Comment: Is she accessing GMail through outlook, or any non-browser stored locally on her computer? Has she allowed her browser to store her password? Does she have any unusual toolbars or add-ons to her browser? Any of the above would allow a bot to access her login information, but anything else would probably be a targeted attack (unlikely, given how the info was used).

Comment: She very rarely uses thunderbird.  I run Norton Internet security and once a month run several malware detection tools. Passwords are stored with lastpass, but like most users, she is perpetually logged into gmail.  I think it's less likely it was anything on the local machine.  Maybe CSRF somehow?

Comment: That's mostly fixed for Firefox (which I assume you're running, based on the fact that you're using Thunderbird), but cookie theft is a possibility if she's always logged in.

Comment: She uses chrome.  Either way, you have to be more technical than 'cookie theft' to get to the bottom of how this would work in principle.

Comment: Have you checked [last account activity](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938)? Has she logged into her account from other points than her computer? (work, friends, etc.)

Comment: If we're to assume that her computer isn't infected, we're left with a fairly limited set of options - an attacker might have run a MiTM or evil twin attack at a public place (although it seems a bit unlikely, given how aggressively SSL is being implemented nowadays), or she might have been the victim of a cross-scripting attack, as you suggested. Either way, @user10008's question is a good one - has she logged on from public places or other devices?

Comment: @user10008 Yes we have checked the last account activity, and no strange activity.  In fact, she hasn't logged in for about a week on her laptop.  She has logged in from her phone on the mobile network and only private networks at friends homes. Though I'm sure this 'hack' could have happened much longer ago than the past week.

Comment: @KnightOfNi MiTM is EXTREMELY unlikely.  Evil twin? Possibly, but probably unlikely.  But again, what I'm looking for is how these attacks would occur IN PRINCIPLE, not just the names of different attacks.  From what I can tell CSRF would be the most likely candidate (though Gmail supposedly fixed holes in their CSRF problem years ago).

Comment: Just throwing this out (I don't think it's too likely, but it is possible): it could be that someone is just screwing with you a bit. They might have spoofed the e-mail addresses of the FRIENDS (domains like Yahoo! haven't published their DKIM policy yet) to waste her time. Have you verified with the friends in question, over the phone or in person?

Comment: @KnightOfNi  I'm pretty sure they spoofed the email (it happened with 3 different contacts) But what I'm most curious is the fact that they know my wife's contacts AT ALL.  How do they know who she knows?  That's the part that no one seems to be able to answer for me.

Comment: Having exhausted most of the ways I know of that an attacker could get your wife's password (since you seem confident nothing was touched on the local computer and nothing was sniffed), I have to agree that if spam was sent out, if was probably Cross-Scripting or another malicious webapp. However, I would note that malicious webapps could grab your wife's contacts from Thunderbird (I believe they don't even encrypt the contacts file) if they had hard drive access (which isn't too hard to get).

Comment: Again, could you PLEASE just explain it in a bit more detail.  I'm not really looking for, it could be X, or Y, or Z.  I'm wondering *HOW* these things occur.  How would 'malicious webapps grab' my wife's contacts?  My guess is that the probability of this is 0.00001% though.

Comment: No one is giving you specifics because we haven't figured out what's wrong. Since it can be assumed that you don't want an encyclopedia of ways to grab a password, I'm trying to figure out what it is first, and then I'll try to explain to your satisfaction. Malicious webapps usually come in two varieties: trojans, which try to get you to interact with a Java, Flash, or ActiveX applet, or the other ones (I forget what they're called at the moment), which exploit bugs in said applets to gain access without your knowledge. Malicious applets CAN appear on legit sites in the form of ads.

Comment: no offence KnightOfNi, but I don't think you know what you're talking about here.  Maybe you're looking for more SE rep or something, but the reason I'm looking for something more than, 'it could be X' is because EVERY example you've given is so unlikely, and you've been completely unable to assess any of the likely mode of attacks.  MiTM? Really?  You really that there's a server between my wife's laptop and gmail intercepting? Really? A milicious 'webapp' is a 'trojan'? Really?  And you cant even remember the name of the 'other ones'.

Comment: This is an INCREDIBLY common problem:
http://goo.gl/rwN9nn
No one gives a good explination and your guessing (maybe it's malware, maybe it's MiTM, maybe it's a bad wifi hotspot) shows that you are not familar with this.  I do appreciate that you want to get to the bottom of this--I do too--but what I'm looking for is someone who knows why this stuff happens, not someone to give me the possibilities.  Given how common this, the security community KNOWS why this happens, but your guesses show that you do not.  It's just not what I'm looking for, sorry, but thank you for taking your time.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't being helpful. I should have guessed it wasn't password theft based on the last account activity thing, but I'm not sure why you discount the possibility of MiTM quite as derisively as you do (I understand why you're discounting it, but I do not think it was unrealistic enough to deserve the "really?"s). While Trojans are not necessarily malicious webapps, the definition laid down by Cisco correlates with the type of webapp I'm describing. While your problem IS common, I hope you're not suggesting everyone who encounters it is the victim of the exact same attack...

Comment: PS - As you well know, you can't get rep for comments here.

Comment: No I'm sure there are many ways, but I'm sure the predominant attack vectors are only a few.  Then the answer would be (best I can give atm): "There are only a few common vectors for contact harvesting 1) Facebook/Google vulnerabilies circa 2007-2009 
http://goo.gl/BGFuey http://goo.gl/fJt0A 2) webscraping + reversing social connections 3) rogue wifi APs 4) evil smartphone apps.  Given gmails encryption and lack of known XSS, injection attacks and pluged holes in Outlook/Thunderbird/Windows to viruses that capture contact lists #1 and to a lesser extent #2 are the predominant attack vectors"

Comment: Joe, you are quick to discount KnightOfNi's suggestions, but they are along the same lines of my own suggestions and I do know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Then by all means, provide the explanation.  The point was that I'm looking for the HOW, not the WHAT.  Anyone can say, 'oh yeah it's just MiTM attack'.  Someone that does know what they are talking about can EXPLAIN it and point to a reason why a given reason accounts for a large number of cases (why it's a high-probability) vector.  If you can't do this, then 'I know what I'm talking about' is nothing more than words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to your first question: no one knows.  Your request for the most common method for contact list harvesting is a tall order.  The problem is although we have estimates of, say, the number of computers infected with viruses, or the number of data breaches, or the number of vulnerable websites, or the number of phishing emails, it's very difficult to know which source is the most common specifically for harvesting contacts for several reasons.  We know that about 40% computers are infected with some sort of malware (bots, worms, viruses, trojans), but only a small percentage of these are for harvesting your contact list per se (many are for key-logging, snooping for financial info, bitcoin mining, and most likely: just sending out lots and lots of spam).  On the other hand we also know that 37.3 million users (Kaspersky) experienced non-virus phishing attacks.

The problem is that our data suffers from selection bias because we only have data from antivirus programs which detect the attack, and because of this we don't know which attacks are the most successful.

As for resources: the best resources usually come from security firms which track these things the best they can.  Here are several reports which describe the best we know about the statistics. But again, don't expect an answer to which source most likely takes people's (your wife's) contact list:

http://media.kaspersky.com/pdf/LK_KSB_2013_spam_EN.pdf
http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/other_resources/b-istr_main_report_v19_21291018.en-us.pdf

But if you're fine with the answer of 'we don't know', I can list how some of the attacks work (HAW) (in no particular order) and how to guard against them (WYCD):

- Data breach - HAW: Facebook/Linked-in/Google or another smaller site or hacked or have a vulnerability of all sorts - WYCD: not much just make sure you use different passwords for each site
- Direct hack - HAW: if a hacker knows enough about you, they might be able to guess your password, then they have direct access to your account - WYCD: make sure you have a secure password over 8 characters at least with no dictionary words.
- Poorly designed website is hacked - HAW: a large number of websites have vulnerablities (XSS, SQL injection, etc).  If any of these have any way to connect you to your contacts this could have happened.  WYCD: Not much you can do about this
- Bad Mobile app - HAW: a mobile app has access to your gmail contact list and is sent to a third party WYCD: don't install apps you don't trust; look at the app permissions you grant
- Wifi snooping HAW: most wifi APs bleed all sorts of personal information to the open. WYCD: use encryption as much as possible (https not http) (gmail has this)
- Phishing - HAW: Either through email or social networking a user is tricked into visiting fake a site has the user enter their login information or asks for this information directly over email and the account is hijacked or, as you mention, get direct access to your email through CSRF. WYCD: Install a good AV program which has a good phishing heuristic
- Malware (Bots, Viruses, Trojans, Worms) - HAW: Although there are all sorts of viruses, a few of them do try and grab your contact list from an executable.  Java vulnerabilities are very popular lately.  Someone will send a java file, and a single double-click and it's installed.  WYCD: only open attachments from trusted sources and make sure you have a good AV program.
- Browser vulnerabilities - HAW: All browsers have vulnerabilities, sometimes visiting a malicious site can trick your browser to installing malware .  WYCD: make sure you have a program (most AVs have it) that warns you about malicious sites - there are also browser plugins that do this. Also keep your browser up to date (and OS) with latest security fixes.

There are actually many more. But I would say these are the 'most common'.  Go through the reports above to get an expert assessment of the state of software and web security.

Answer (score 3):

I have helped people who have experienced exactly the same thing that you are describing and it was simply the result of an infection. A program connects to her gmail account, and searches for emails in her contacts and folders, including the deleted items folder. Then, spam is sent out.

I know that you have scanned her machine, but scans do not always catch the very new variants of malware. In the last case I worked on, I was able to trace the infection to a file the person opened that was also sent to her by one of her contacts.

Comment: Which virus?  What is the prevalence rate?  Again, I really want to know why so many people have these problems.  But thank you for your input.

Comment: @Joe I am now completely confused about what you are looking for. You asked for the steps concerning how this can occur, I provide steps that I have personally seen, and you then ask for the prevalence rate of the particular strain I saw? Why do so many people have these problems? Because many people are uncareful enough to click on things that are infected.

Comment: And how do you know this?  My original question said "What are the **most likely** steps for how this 'hack' occurs?"  Are you sure that because you know of *A* way (which you don't seem to have any information about), that this means this is the *MOST LIKELY* way?  Can you name *ANY* virus that does this?  'Viral-inviters'/contact-scrapers, Phishing CSRF, or the FB/Google breaches seem *MUCH* more likely.  I'm sorry, even it was all viruses, your one example of a virus that you have no information about is not enough to extrapolate to answer my question, that's not how evidence works.

Comment: @Joe I am an expert at getting people to click on things that they shouldn't. I own and run SelfPhish.com. If you want to discuss the LIKELY ways this hack can happen, then you have to come up with a very good reason why an errant clicker is NOT the likely scenario. All I have to go on is what you've told me, and I am working completely in the dark because I do not have access to the primary data. I have dealt with 3 different types of malware in 3 different incidents. Can I name them? No. But why do I need to? I can't help if all you do is dismiss suggestions.

Comment: And I have a friend that owns 3 internet security companies, has a Ph.D in the area, and has worked in the industry for 30 years and he said that viruses are not a major source of this type of harvesting.  Unless you  have something more than, "Because I said so", I'm sorry, your word just wont cut it.

Comment: @Joe I'm sorry - you either misunderstood your friend, or your friend is incorrect. Botnets are a major issue and they do this sort of harvesting. Botnets are most commonly built by infection, propagated by this very method (infect, harvest, spread). Even if your friend is that experienced, you are not. As you feel that you already know the truth, I am disengaging from you. I can't help you if you are predisposed to antagonism.

Comment: Look, all I want, as I said in my original post, is a resource that explains the most common method, not some "trust me, I know what I'm talking about" reply.  You say you know a program that connects to gmail, but you can't name the program? In fact you can't name any features about this virus whatsoever.  If you are an expert, you have to admit that the evidence you provided is a LONG way to proving the MOST LIKELY scenario. If you could provide ANYTHING (a link, a name, a whitepaper) ANYTHING, then maybe it would help.

Comment: Joe, ask your friend. If he really owns 3 internet security companies, he can give you a very good lecture on the subject.
@schroeder is right. Botnets are the biggest source of email harvesting today, by very, very far. If you want a link, try this http://bit.ly/VOvwT8

Comment: http://goo.gl/nmbQr1